# Is short circuit evaluation a language feature in C/C++ or compiler implementation

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, g++

I'm wondering if short circuit evaluation of

```
long param = 0;
if ( functAWithSideEffects(&param) || funcBWithSideEffects(&param) )
```

Can be relied on.  For example, if funcAWithSideEffects returns true, will the compiler evaluation funcBWithSideEffects?  Is short circuit evaluation a language feature or a compiler implementation detail?

Comment: Check by reading C++11 standard, practically [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: I'm sure it's buried in the somewhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It can be relied on.

The [C standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14p4) guarantees it (emphasis mine):

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
> a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated.**

and while C++ diverges from C in several ways, I'm 99.99% sure short circuit evaluation isn't one of them.

A similar guarantee can be found for `&&`.